# Convert a python list of strings into bytecode to write for writing into a file

Tags: python, arrays, file, keras, byte

I am trying to train a Keras model (LipNet) and on begin training, it opens a file with `wb` and tries to write the header contained in a list. However, I get this error:

```
File "c:\users\fahim\documents\lipnet\lipnet\lipreading\callbacks.py", line 77, in on_train_begin
    csvw.writerow(['Epoch', 'Samples', 'Mean CER', 'Mean CER (Norm)', 'Mean WER', 'Mean WER (Norm)', 'Mean BLEU', 'Mean BLEU (Norm)'])
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I have looked this problem up and tried many things suggested such as putting `b` in front of the strings,

```
csvw.writerow([b'Epoch', b'Samples', b'Mean CER', b'Mean CER (Norm)', b'Mean WER', b'Mean WER (Norm)', b'Mean BLEU', b'Mean BLEU (Norm)'])
```

and experimented with turning lists into bytecode.

```
>>>bytes([1,2,3])
b'\x01\x02\x03'
>>>bytes(["a", "b"]) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    bytes(["a", "b"])
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Here is the [full code](https://github.com/rizkiarm/LipNet/blob/bec592aa1e66378bc7ab33f6110f1c8a431b3b9a/lipnet/lipreading/callbacks.py) that opens the file:

(snippet)

```
def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        with open(os.path.join(self.output_dir, 'stats.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile: #wb -> w
            csvw = csv.writer(csvfile)
            csvw.writerow([b'Epoch', b'Samples', b'Mean CER', b'Mean CER (Norm)', b'Mean WER', b'Mean WER (Norm)', b'Mean BLEU', b'Mean BLEU (Norm)'])
```

By the way, the code also uses pickle if that helps. How can the `csvw` write the row in bytecode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv` always wants text files, not binary files, but you can try to emulate that by doing this:

```
with open(os.path.join(self.output_dir, 'stats.csv'), 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline=''):
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem here although there is another `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects`

Comment: This is a different, unrelated error. Have you tried Googling around?